# Cannot create poolname : no such pool or dataset

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I destroyed an existing zpool by running

> zpool destroy -f poolname

Now I try to create a new pool

```
sudo zpool create -f poolname xbd0 xbd1 xbd2 xbd3
cannot create 'poolname': no such pool or dataset
```

Answer (score 0):

We had encrypted disks in place which have .eli extension and I had to run

> sudo zpool create -f pool xbd0p1.eli xbd1p1.eli xbd2p1.eli xbd3p1.eli

Comment: That does seem like the wrong error message, as the problem is the disk device (xbd0 etc) did not exist.

Comment: Yes, that was misleading and I spent hours googling the error.